# How to disable "add comment form" from a OG group content?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

When I'm showing content that belongs to a group I don't want to show the "comment form" to users that don't belong to that group. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the group permission page, and uncheck the comment option for non-members.

Comment: I don't have an option for "comments" on the "admin > organic grous > global permissions" page.

Comment: It should be there .. first try with fresh drupal installation.